# Run Keyword If Test Failed BDD Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, bdd, gherkin

I have a .robot  file with settings where I import keywords and Test Cases in Gherkin/BDD.
There is an issue if one test cases fails, due to the nature of the testing all the other test cases in the .robot file fail.

Before I run the test I initialize the test with a keyword.

I would like to run that keyword to re-initialize and run the next test case in the file.

```
*** Settings ***

Resource          My_keywords.robot

*** Test Cases ***

000 Test Inicialization 000
        Inicialize test

001 First test 001
        Test something
```

Comment: Have you considered using a "Test Setup" in the settings section? It's the type of thing it is designed for. E.g. "Test Setup  Inicialize test" then you can remove 000 test. It's best to avoid chaining tests otherwise you'll always need to run them in a specific sequence

Comment: So its better to separate multiple tests into multiple .robot files? I will try what you suggest and read more on this subject.

Comment: I mean, they can be in the same .robot file but I wouldn't have Test Case 001 rely on something that was setup in Test Case 000. Instead either do a "Test Setup" in settings section or if it's just for one test in the file you can do [Setup] at the test level

There is example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101372/test-setup-and-teardown-for-each-test-case-in-a-test-suite-in-robot-framework-us

Comment: Test Setup - what happens at the beginning of every test
Suite Setup - what happens at the beginning of every suite (file)

This is very important. For example, you only need to connect to DB or open your browser once per test suite. This can save you lot of runtime.

Comment: @LubosJerabek, that's true. I should have said either depending on context of what is in initialization. I always tend to jump straight to Test Setup for some reason.